# Visiting an undefined Path or a error page results in hard reload in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, next.js13

Visiting an undefined Path or an error page results in a hard reload in Next.js which in turn leads to my context getting back to its default state (i.e value stored in `userProfile` state variable gets back to null)

I have a layout that I use {stucture: Sidebar and main}, in Sidebar Component I am displaying user email which I am getting from my context hook as a state variable.

But when I click on an undefined path or write it manually in url I throw a custom error page which goes back to index page('/'),but I am losing my state back to `null` (context) because of this.

my context file looks like this

```js
import { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ userProfile, setUserProfile }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserContext() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}
```

I am setting my state inside (on success)login handler on the login page.

Is there any workaround or should I use local storage for this
For now, I am fetching userProfile again on index page when he transitions back to the index page.
I think local storage would have been a better choice

Comment: I fixed my issue by not setting the state in any place but just inside the context file, so, in short, I am fetching the user's profile data inside the context.js file, and there itself I am setting the state which can be used anywhere . If someone comes across the same problem mention me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by not setting the state in any place but just inside the context file, so, in short, I am fetching the user's profile data inside the context.js file, and there itself I am setting the state which can be used anywhere . If someone comes across the same problem mention me!

My Context.js file looks like this

```
import { createContext, useState,useEffect, useContext } from 'react';

 const UserContext = createContext();

 export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
   const fetchUserProfile = async () => {
    try {
     const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_DOMAIN + '/userProfile');
       const userData = await res.json();
       setUserProfile(userData);
       setLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching user profile:", error);
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

 fetchUserProfile();
}, []);

 return (
  <UserContext.Provider value={{ userProfile, setUserProfile,loading }}>
   {children}
 </UserContext.Provider>
 );
}

export function useUserContext() {
 return useContext(UserContext);
}
```